# ImageMagick - Under what conditions does it use GPU?

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

We need to resize many images a day. I'm thinking that we should buy two decent GPUs and stick them in an old desktop PC.

However, Image Magick may not be able to use the GPU on Windows (I can't see that it uses DirectX). It may not be able to use the GPU on Linux, since Linux may not have the OS hooks needed. It may only be able to use the GPU on a Mac.

I'm just guessing.

Does anyone know with any certainty which OS is best for this tool?

Thanks! Luke

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently this *graphics* tool does not use the *graphics* processing unit by default.

https://superuser.com/questions/718556/imagemagick-for-windows-not-listing-opencl-as-enabled?rq=1

You have to learn how to compile the source on Linux with a special switch in order to get the tool to be any good at anything.

Answer (score 2):

ImageMagick uses the [OpenCL](http://www.khronos.org/opencl/) library for any GPU calls, and they do provide a driver for all standard OS's (Windows/Mac/Linux).  So for GPU driver compatibility, whatever OS you choose should not be a problem.